# Calculating energy released by using binding energy VS mass difference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Please take a look at (C). I have no prob with (a) and (b) but some values are needed from (a) and (b) in order to perform a calculation in (C).

For (C), I wonder why I got different answers from two different methods.
I used binding energy per nucleon in method 1 and got 182 MeV in the blue box.
However, with method 2, using the mass difference between products and reactants, I got 200 MeV instead (in the red box). After checking my answers with mark scheme, I found that the first one (182 MeV) is correct. Why method 2 is wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Ps. I have checked my calculation again and again. Thus, I don't think it is about the numerical mistakes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this strange textbook/test? **Short answer:** comparing binding energies -method 1- is wrong in this case. Use *mass excess* or *amu*.

**First:** I get quite another values, check it in literature...

B.E. per nucleon

`139La 139,57     8.37806`

`95Mo   95,42     8.64867`

`235U  235,92     7.59091 MeV`

Q reaction = `207.788 MeV` (when I use mass excess differences -I like them more - or when I use a.m.u with 931.5 MeV as in your method 2)

**Second:**

The given question is **not really just about a nuclear reaction**. It is a reaction with number of subsequent decays. **Seven $\beta-$ decays.**

When I use your method of comparison of *binding energies* on both sides (*method 1*) I get `202.31014 MeV`, which is also different from Q, similar problem as in your example.

What actually happens - I show on example of mass excess. Let us symbolically rewrite the reaction with masses (notation is mex(A,Z)):

$m_{ex}(235,92) \rightarrow m_{ex}(139,57) + m_{ex}(95,42) + m_{ex}(1,0)$

I omitted one neutron on each side for simplicity. If you substract the sides, you get `207.788 MeV`.

Now we write the new formula with *binding energies* on each side and compare to the previous

$m_{ex}(235,92) - 92\cdot m_{ex}(1,1) -  143\cdot m_{ex}(1,0)\rightarrow m_{ex}(139,57)  - 57\cdot m_{ex}(1,1) -  82\cdot m_{ex}(1,0)+ m_{ex}(95,42) - 42\cdot m_{ex}(1,1) -  53\cdot m_{ex}(1,0) + m_{ex}(1,0) - m_{ex}(1,0) $

just for illustration I left the last neutron *binding energy* explicitly. After a simplification you get

$m_{ex}(235,92) - 92\cdot m_{ex}(1,1) -  143\cdot m_{ex}(1,0)\rightarrow m_{ex}(139,57) + m_{ex}(95,42) - 99\cdot m_{ex}(1,1) -  135\cdot m_{ex}(1,0) $

If you wanted to get the same with mass excess a(or a.m.u.) AND binding energies, the terms with mex(1,0) and mex(1,1) must be the same on both sides. They are not.

**Third:**

If it was just a nuclear reaction ($^{235}U + n\rightarrow ^{139}I + 
 ^{95}Y + 2n$), your *binding energies* formula would *magically* work in the case. In my case,I get the difference that is `5.477 MeV`, which is exactly $7\times$ mass difference of proton and neutron $m_{ex}(1,0)-m_{ex}(1,1)$ `=0.7823 MeV`

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. It's A-level exam. Thank you so much for your help. I am going to vote this answer up once I have enough reputations. Thank youuuu:)))

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 involved the condition counting the kinetic energy of neutrons and electrons which has been ignored by the question.
That's the reason why you got two different answers.